# Yii2 Transaction- Updates previous uncommitted value plus new commited value?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, yii2

I am trying to implement transaction in yii2 basic framework. I have written a small test script for testing transaction. All goes well except one exception. When I am running the transaction script and stops it immediately no changes happens in db. But when I am running the script till completion of the script the changes done in database but the changes are not in desired manner. For example if my initial amount is 1000.00 and runs the script having amount variable amount+100 and if I stops it immediately no changes in the database but when I am running the script till the completion of the script and after that the value of amount 1000+100+100 = 1200, instead of 1100. Here is my code.

```
   public function actionIndex() 
{

    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;

    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
    try 
    {
        $command = $connection->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1');

        $command->execute();

        $command = $connection->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1');
        $command->execute();

        $command = $connection->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1');
        $command->execute();

        $command = $connection->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1');
        $command->execute();
        sleep(10);

        $transaction->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) 
    {
        $transaction->rollback();
    }
```

I think the problem is with my rollback which is not executing. Any help will be much appreciating.

Comment: In your code,I see you are incrementing amount by 1 not 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not binded with transactions. Try to execute your code with/without transaction and compare result. 
Moreover I recommend to use more simple syntax:

```php
\Yii::$app->db->transaction(function(){

    \Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1')
        ->execute();

    \Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1')
        ->execute();

    \Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1')
        ->execute();

    \Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand('UPDATE test_transaction1 SET amount=amount+1 WHERE sno=1')
        ->execute();

    sleep(10);
});
```

Comment: Same issue. Nothing changes with this this

Comment: What result if you comment \Yii::$app->db->transaction(function(){ .. }) wrapper? (without transaction)